# ngnix proxy_pass HTML resources

Tags: nginx, proxy, html, resources

I'm setting up a reverse proxy that connects to different localhost ports with different services.

This is the NGINX site configuration:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/include/php;

        location /Random_Folder {
                rewrite ^/Random_Folder(.*) /$1  break;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        }
}
```

I can see that by accessing to: "http://myserver.com:80/Random_Folder" the request go to "http://localhost:9000" as it should.
But additional resources on the page fail to load (JS, CSS) and they all point to the root document folder "/" instead of "/Random_Folder".

Is there anything in the configuration I'm missing to make this fully functional ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not keep random_folder or some other name to identify the requests ?

Comment: Because I  won't be able to redirect to a different localhost port - the proxy_pass is written dynamically and there are situation where there are more than one "location" to a different localhost port

Comment: Ok, but if you rewrite the URL to / then subsequent requests for css and other files will be relative to that URL. You need to write a rule for both / and random_folder to deal with it.

Comment: Ok, that sound interesting approach - can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Nothing sophisticated, just the same rule for / so that your /my.css goes to the right server.

Comment: Can you please give an example